# How can i convert convert json to object with different field names GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

how can i convert this json:

```
[{"id":"0","value":1010},{"id":"1","value":"1000"},{"id":"2","value":"1111"}]
```

to single object having object having fields.

```
value0;(corresponds to id of value 0) it should be 1010

value1;(corresponds to id of value 1) it should be 1000

value2;(corresponds to id of value 2)
```

using `GSON` how can i implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Java Class according to your json object field like:-

```
public class Example {

    private String id;
    private String value;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }



}
```

And  one more class to represent arrays of json value to JAVA objects:-

```
public class JSONExample {

    List<Example> examples;

    public List<Example> getExamples() {
        return examples;
    }

    public void setExamples(List<Example> examples) {
        this.examples = examples;
    }

}
```

Then you can loop your JSON object/array to create **"Example"** java 
 Object and using the same create **JSONExample**  object.
Thats It.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be something like below :

```
  String yourJson = "[{"id":"0","value":1010},{"id":"1","value":"1000"},{"id":"2","value":"1111"}]";

    Gson gson = new Gson();  
    YourObject[] yourObjectArr= gson.fromJson(yourJson, YourObject[].class);



       class YourObject
        {
        String id;
        String value;
        }
```